# Como arrendondar parcelas igualando o total?

Tags: php, matemática

```
     $meses = 3;
     $valor = 1000
     $valor_parcela = $valor  / $meses;

                for ($i = 1;$i <= $meses; $i++) {
                      $date_sum_month = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+{$i} month", strtotime($date)));
                      array_push($boletos, ["numero" => $i, "vencimento" => date_sum_month, "valor" => $valor_parcela]);
                     }
return json_encode($boletos);
```

Resultado do meu código:

```
1 - 333,333
2 - 333,333
3 - 333,333
```

Desejado:

```
1 - 333
2 - 333
3 - 334
```

Comment: Use o método floor: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floor.php

Comment: André, verifique se `$valor_parcela = floor($valor  / $meses);` resolve seu problema, se sim,  explico para você na resposta

Comment: Luiz Augusto fiz, porém o floor arredonda para menos.
doc: floor — Arredonda frações para baixo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa fazer a diferença da soma das parcelas arredondas para zero casas e adicionar na última parcela. Então você quer fazer duas coisas, calcular todas parcelas sem as casas decimais, e depois modificar a última para garantir que a soma delas dê o mesmo que o valor original. Poderia fazer considerando um certo número de casas decimais, 1, 2 ou até mais, ainda que ultrapasse os centavos que usamos, basta dizer quantas casas quer arredondar.

```
$meses = 3;
$valor = 1000;
$boletos = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $meses; $i++) array_push($boletos, round($valor / $meses, 0));
$boletos[$meses - 1] += $valor - array_sum($boletos);
print_r($boletos);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EtWKz9). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FillPaymentsphp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/FillPayments.php).